# Destination not being set while uploading files using multer and gcloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, blob, multer

I am trying to upload files in a specific folder in my google storage bucket. I wrote my code using [Google documentations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage)

app.js

```
const multerMid = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
        // no larger than 5mb.
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
},
});

app.disable("x-powered-by");
app.use(
    multerMid.fields([
        { name: "avatar", maxCount: 1 },
        { name: "gallery", maxCount: 8 },
    ])
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/uploads", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const myFile = req.files;
        console.log(myFile);
        const imageUrl = await uploadImage(myFile.gallery[0]);
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Upload was successful",
            data: imageUrl,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

uploadimage function

```
const uploadImage = (file) =>
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { originalname, buffer } = file;

    const blob = bucket.file(originalname.replace(/\s+/g, "_"));
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        destination: "documents/image.png",
        resumable: false,
    });
    blobStream
        .on("finish", () => {
            const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
            resolve(publicUrl);
        })
        .on("error", () => {
            reject(`Unable to upload image, something went wrong`);
        })
        .end(buffer);
});
```

Here, i am setting the destination as documents/image.png but the file is still storing in the bucket root and not in the documents folder. How can i make the files get stored in a specific folder in bucket?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured out the way to store a file in a particular subdirectory in google storage bucket.Google stores a file in its bucket with a name which contains it path too. For eg, if an image name `xyz.jpg` is store in `abc` folder in `mnp` bucket. The filename will be `mnp/abc/xyz.jpg`. So, to save a file in a particular directory, we just have to add the path in the original file name.

```
const uploadImage = (file) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { originalname, buffer } = file;

    const blob = 
    bucket.file(originalname.replace(originalname,"document/"+originalname));
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        resumable: false,
    });
    blobStream
    .on("finish", () => {
        const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
        resolve(publicUrl);
    })
    .on("error", () => {
        reject(`Unable to upload image, something went wrong`);
    })
    .end(buffer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`createWriteStream`  has no `property` named `destination` on its `configuration` option!

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#CreateWriteStreamOptions

There is the `uploadOptions` object:
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#UploadOptions

Solution: You should use `upload` convenience method (which wraps `createWriteStream`) and pass the `uploadOptions` object to it which as a `destionation` property!
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload

Comment: By this way, i am not able to upload the image to the cloud. I am getting an error - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\Ezasptal\aditya\cristiano-ronaldo-3840x2160-portugal-real-madrid-soccer-4k-19809.jpg'. The link to my code - https://codeshare.io/5D1OeO

Comment: Actually, i got the point. Earlier, while using createwritestream , i was able to pickup image from anywhere in my local machine.But, while using upload convenience method, the file should be present in my root folder. If, i have to get file from frontend and post it in google cloud, createWriteStream can do  it without saving it in the server, but i think the upload method will require the file to be saved in the server first.